# Дублируется код при ajax помогите исправить

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

как есть сейчас

запись1
запись2
запись3

когда добавляю новую запись

запись1
запись2
запись3
запись1
запись2
запись3
запись4(новая)

как ето исправить ? когда обновляю страницу все норм

```
$queryCredit = "SELECT * FROM `credit`";
$resCredit = mysqli_query($conection, $queryCredit);


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resCredit)) {

    $output[] = [
            "id" => (int)$row['id'],
            "description" => $row['description'],
            "grn" => (int)$row['grn'],
            "pln" => (int)$row['pln'],
            "eur" => (int)$row['eur'],
            "usd" => (int)$row['usd'],
        ];
}

echo json_encode($output);







data.forEach(function(item) {
table_kred = "<tr><td style='text-align: left'>" + item.description + "</td><td>" + item.grn + "</td><td>" + item.pln + "</td><td>" + item.eur + "</td><td>" + item.usd + "</td><td><a href='?kredit=1&id=" + item.id + "' class='delete-kredit'>Видалити кредит</a></td></tr>";
                        $('#table-get-kre').append($(table_kred));
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нужно очистить таблицу

```
$('#table-get-kre').empty();

data.forEach(function(item) {
table_kred = "<tr><td style='text-align: left'>" + item.description + "</td><td>" + item.grn + "</td><td>" + item.pln + "</td><td>" + item.eur + "</td><td>" + item.usd + "</td><td><a href='?kredit=1&id=" + item.id + "' class='delete-kredit'>Видалити кредит</a></td></tr>";
                        $('#table-get-kre').append($(table_kred));
})
```

Comment: Все норм только стили css от bootstrap пропали (((

Comment: Не должны. Они же на сам тег <table> навешиваются.

Comment: Какая версия bootstrap? Какой браузер?

Comment: bootstrap 3, hrom

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0N_1p6wnchMTWFjQ2lwVmh4OXc

Comment: А до обновления данных как выглядит? Честно говоря, пока никаких предположений нет.

Comment: добавил <thead> и <tbody> и все норм)

Comment: можеш еще помоч с удалением?

Comment: В тег <tr> добавь атрибут data-id равный $row['id']. При удалении 

$('tr').each(function(){

if($this).data('id') == data)
{
$(this).remove();
}
})

Comment: <a href='#' data-id='" + item.id + "' class='delete-kredit'>Видалити кредит</a>

Comment: Вот так норм будет  ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0N_1p6wnchMQnN3NkV1WmdjdHM

Comment: @AlexKizyma, вместо предложения правки, сильно меняющей чужой ответ - можно дать свой ответ, сопроводить комментариями и пояснениями. Возможно такой ответ будет более полезен, чем правка ответа, сильно меняющая содержимое ответа.

Comment: @AlexKizyma Это уже в обработчик ответа при удалении надо запихнуть. Соответственно, сервер после удаления должен вернуть id.

Comment: оброботчик php у меня вот запрос например смотри ниже пример